# Instance of 'Future<String>' instead of showing the value

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Iam using flutter and I am trying to get a value from shared_preferences that I had set before, and display it in a text widget. but i get Instance of `Future<String>` instead of the value. here is my code:

```
Future<String> getPhone() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String patientPhone = prefs.getString('patientPhone').toString();
        print(patientPhone);

    return patientPhone;
  }

Future<String> phoneOfPatient = getPhone();

Center(child: Text('${phoneOfPatient}'),))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is `await` missing before `prefs.getString(` and use `setState()` instead of returning the value. `build()` can't use `await`.

```
  String _patientPhone;

  Future<void> getPhone() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String patientPhone = await /*added */ prefs.getString('patientPhone');
    print(patientPhone);

    setState(() => _patientPhone = patientPhone);
  }

  build() {
    ...
    Center(child: _patientPhone != null ? Text('${_patientPhone}') : Container(),))
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting that error but the value that is shown is null and I am sure that it is not null because I am using it in another file(that file is a http response and does not have a builder)

Comment: Did you use my `_patientPhone != null ...` code? The value will be `null` at first because the code to get it is async and will only result in a value != null after a while. When Flutter runs `build()` in the meantime, the value will still be `null`.

Comment: Does `print(patientPhone);` ever print anything?

Comment: in other files it does, but here it does not.

Comment: also here with the previous codes it did show the phone, but when I changed it to ur code, it does not print anything

Comment: Try without `await /*added */`. It seems it is not required here. `Instance of 'Future<String>'` seems to be coming from another part of your cod.

Comment: If there is no phone number stored under this key, then you don't get one. I can't know from the provided information.

Comment: no there is a phone, because i am using it to receive response from the server and i am getting the response, also it gets printed in other files

Comment: Everything is possible but I can't verify from here and depend on information you provide. If there were a phone `print(patientPhone);` would print it though.

Comment: https://github.com/mojtabaparvar/myapp                                                                       this is my code on github . you can take a look at it

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have the option to use `await` or `async` you can do the following.

```
getPhone().then((value){
 print(value);
});
```

and then assign a variable to them. From that, you'll have the result from the `value`.

Comment: Please how can i set the value, mine is only active inside the function not outside,